# Jquery scrollTop behaving oddly with JqueryUI Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, scrolltop

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ckanoab/jqmyA/9/)

Have a list of stores in the Accordion control inside a height constrained div and am trying to scroll the active panel fully into view.

```
$("#stores").accordion({
    heightStyle: "fixed",
    icons: false,
    activate: function (event,ui) {
        $("#stores").scrollTop($(ui.newHeader).position().top-5);
    }
});
```

This should bring the newly activated header and it's accompanying panel to the top of the parent div with 5px margin but it doesn't... Has been driving me crazy for days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stores").accordion({
        heightStyle: "fixed",
        icons: false,
        activate: function (event,ui) {
            var scrollTop = $("#stores").scrollTop();
            var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
            $("#stores").scrollTop(scrollTop + top -5);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3qFfg/)